# Write data to a CSV file with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, writetofile

very new to the JavaScript world. I am trying to modify this js file to write data a CSV file. This code is available as a Package on GitHub, but I want to take it a step further by collected the data.

How do get this code to write the data, it creates the data, but I not sure how to get it constantly write the data received.

Here is the Code - you can see my attempt to write the data at the end of the code. Any help would be very much appreciated, have done a lot of research, but just can get this to come together.

I tried about everything I can find on the web on how to write data, all the examples I see are showing hard data to be written to the csv file, I want to capture the data from all the variables in the code and write all the lines of data to the csv file.

Thank you

```
var PORT = 20127;
var HOST = '192.168.xx.xx';

const express = require('express');
const app = express();

//used to write to the csv file
const fs = require('fs');

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "\*");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
next();
});

var dgram = require('dgram');
var server = dgram.createSocket('udp4');

let obj = {};

server.on('listening', function () {
var address = server.address();
console.log('UDP Server listening on ' + address.address + ":" + address.port);
});

server.on('message', function (message, remote) {
let jump = 0;

    obj.isRaceOn = message.readInt32LE(jump);
    jump += 4;
    obj.timestampMS = message.readUInt32LE(jump); //Getting wrong data
    jump += 4;
    obj.engineMaxRpm = message.readFloatLE(jump);
    jump += 4;
    obj.engineIdleRpm = message.readFloatLE(jump);
    jump += 4;
    obj.currentEngineRpm = message.readFloatLE(jump);
    jump += 4;
    
    obj.accelerationX = message.readFloatLE(jump); //In the car's local space; X = right, Y = up, Z = forward
    jump += 4;
    obj.accelerationY = message.readFloatLE(jump);
    jump += 4;
    obj.accelerationZ = message.readFloatLE(jump);
    jump += 4;
    
    obj.velocityX = message.readFloatLE(jump); //In the car's local space; X = right, Y = up, Z = forward
    jump += 4;
    obj.velocityY = message.readFloatLE(jump);
    jump += 4;
    obj.velocityZ = message.readFloatLE(jump);
    jump += 4;
    
    obj.angularVelocityX = message.readFloatLE(jump); //In the car's local space; X = pitch, Y = yaw, Z = roll
    jump += 4;
    obj.angularVelocityY = message.readFloatLE(jump);
    jump += 4;
    obj.angularVelocityZ = message.readFloatLE(jump);
    jump += 4;
    
    obj.yaw = message.readFloatLE(jump);
    jump += 4;
    obj.pitch = message.readFloatLE(jump);
    jump += 4;
    obj.roll = message.readFloatLE(jump);
    jump += 4;
    
    obj.normalizedSuspensionTravelFrontLeft = message.readFloatLE(jump); // Suspension travel normalized: 0.0f = max stretch; 1.0 = max compression
    jump += 4;
    obj.normalizedSuspensionTravelFrontRight = message.readFloatLE(jump);
    jump += 4;
    obj.normalizedSuspensionTravelRearLeft = message.readFloatLE(jump);
    jump += 4;
    obj.normalizedSuspensionTravelRearRight = message.readFloatLE(jump);
    jump += 4;
    
    obj.tireSlipRatioFrontLeft = message.readFloatLE(jump); // Tire normalized slip ratio, = 0 means 100% grip and |ratio| > 1.0 means loss of grip.
    jump += 4;
    obj.tireSlipRatioFrontRight = message.readFloatLE(jump);
    jump += 4;
    obj.tireSlipRatioRearLeft = message.readFloatLE(jump);
    jump += 4;
    obj.tireSlipRatioRearRight = message.readFloatLE(jump);
    jump += 4;
    
    obj.wheelRotationSpeedFrontLeft = message.readFloatLE(jump); // Wheel rotation speed radians/sec.
    jump += 4; 
    obj.wheelRotationSpeedFrontRight = message.readFloatLE(jump);
    jump += 4;
    obj.wheelRotationSpeedRearLeft = message.readFloatLE(jump);
    jump += 4;
    obj.wheelRotationSpeedRearRight = message.readFloatLE(jump);
    jump += 4;
    
    obj.wheelOnRumbleStripFrontLeft = message.readFloatLE(jump); // = 1 when wheel is on rumble strip, = 0 when off.
    jump += 4;
    obj.wheelOnRumbleStripFrontRight = message.readFloatLE(jump);
    jump += 4;
    obj.wheelOnRumbleStripRearLeft = message.readFloatLE(jump);
    jump += 4;
    obj.wheelOnRumbleStripRearRight = message.readFloatLE(jump);
    jump += 4;
    
    obj.wheelInPuddleDepthFrontLeft = message.readFloatLE(jump); // = from 0 to 1, where 1 is the deepest puddle
    jump += 4;
    obj.wheelInPuddleDepthFrontRight = message.readFloatLE(jump);
    jump += 4;
    obj.wheelInPuddleDepthRearLeft = message.readFloatLE(jump);
    jump += 4;
    obj.wheelInPuddleDepthRearRight = message.readFloatLE(jump);
    jump += 4;
    
    obj.surfaceRumbleFrontLeft = message.readFloatLE(jump); // Non-dimensional surface rumble values passed to controller force feedback
    jump += 4;
    obj.surfaceRumbleFrontRight = message.readFloatLE(jump);
    jump += 4;
    obj.surfaceRumbleRearLeft = message.readFloatLE(jump);
    jump += 4;
    obj.surfaceRumbleRearRight = message.readFloatLE(jump);
    jump += 4;
    
    obj.tireSlipAngleFrontLeft = message.readFloatLE(jump); // Tire normalized slip angle, = 0 means 100% grip and |angle| > 1.0 means loss of grip.
    jump += 4;
    obj.tireSlipAngleFrontRight = message.readFloatLE(jump);
    jump += 4;
    obj.tireSlipAngleRearLeft = message.readFloatLE(jump);
    jump += 4;
    obj.tireSlipAngleRearRight = message.readFloatLE(jump);
    jump += 4;
    
    obj.tireCombinedSlipFrontLeft = message.readFloatLE(jump); // Tire normalized combined slip, = 0 means 100% grip and |slip| > 1.0 means loss of grip.
    jump += 4;
    obj.tireCombinedSlipFrontRight = message.readFloatLE(jump);
    jump += 4;
    obj.tireCombinedSlipRearLeft = message.readFloatLE(jump);
    jump += 4;
    obj.tireCombinedSlipRearRight = message.readFloatLE(jump);
    jump += 4;
    
    obj.suspensionTravelMetersFrontLeft = message.readFloatLE(jump); // Actual suspension travel in meters
    jump += 4;
    obj.suspensionTravelMetersFrontRight = message.readFloatLE(jump);
    jump += 4;
    obj.suspensionTravelMetersRearLeft = message.readFloatLE(jump);
    jump += 4;
    obj.suspensionTravelMetersRearRight = message.readFloatLE(jump);
    jump += 4;
    
    obj.carOrdinal = message.readInt32LE(jump); //Unique ID of the car make/model
    jump += 4;
    obj.carClass = message.readInt32LE(jump); //Between 0 (D -- worst cars) and 7 (X class -- best cars) inclusive 
    jump += 4;
    obj.carPerformanceIndex = message.readInt32LE(jump); //Between 100 (slowest car) and 999 (fastest car) inclusive
    jump += 4;
    obj.drivetrainType = message.readInt32LE(jump); //Corresponds to EDrivetrainType; 0 = FWD, 1 = RWD, 2 = AWD
    jump += 4;
    obj.numCylinders = message.readInt32LE(jump); //Number of cylinders in the engine
    jump += 4;
    
    //Position (meters)
    obj.positionX = message.readFloatLE(jump);
    jump += 4;
    obj.positionY = message.readFloatLE(jump);
    jump += 4;
    obj.positionZ = message.readFloatLE(jump);
    jump += 4;
    
    obj.speed = message.readFloatLE(jump); // meters per second
    jump += 4;
    obj.power = message.readFloatLE(jump); // watts
    jump += 4;
    obj.torque = message.readFloatLE(jump); // newton meter
    jump += 4;
    
    obj.tireTempFrontLeft = message.readFloatLE(jump);
    jump += 4;
    obj.tireTempFrontRight = message.readFloatLE(jump);
    jump += 4;
    obj.tireTempRearLeft = message.readFloatLE(jump);
    jump += 4;
    obj.tireTempRearRight = message.readFloatLE(jump);
    jump += 4;
    
    obj.boost = message.readFloatLE(jump);
    jump += 4;
    obj.fuel = message.readFloatLE(jump);
    jump += 4;
    obj.distanceTraveled = message.readFloatLE(jump);
    jump += 4;
    obj.bestLap = message.readFloatLE(jump); // seconds
    jump += 4;
    obj.lastLap = message.readFloatLE(jump); // seconds
    jump += 4;
    obj.currentLap = message.readFloatLE(jump); // seconds
    jump += 4;
    obj.currentRaceTime = message.readFloatLE(jump); // seconds
    jump += 4;
    
    obj.lapNumber = message.readUInt16LE(jump);
    jump += 2;
    obj.racePosition = message.readUInt8(jump);
    jump += 1;
    
    obj.accel = message.readUInt8(jump); // 0 - 255
    jump += 1;
    obj.brake = message.readUInt8(jump); // 0 - 255
    jump += 1;
    obj.clutch = message.readUInt8(jump);
    jump += 1;
    obj.handBrake = message.readUInt8(jump);
    jump += 1;
    obj.gear = message.readUInt8(jump);
    jump += 1;
    obj.steer = message.readUInt8(jump);
    jump += 1;
    
    obj.normalizedDrivingLine = message.readUInt8(jump);
    jump += 1;
    obj.normalizedAIBrakeDifference = message.readUInt8(jump);
    jump += 1;
    
    
    
    
    
    console.log(remote.address + ':' + remote.port + ' - (' + obj.isRaceOn + '), Gear:' + obj.gear + " - Tire:" + obj.tireSlipRatioFrontLeft);

//const fs = require('fs');
const writeTofile = ()=\>{

let header = "handbrake ,gear, steer, lapnumber";

let data = 'obj.gear, tire, steer, lapnumber \\n';

let csv_data = header + data

console.log(csv_data)
fs.writeFileSync("user.csv" , csv_data , "utf-8")
}

writeTofile()

});

server.bind(PORT, HOST);

app.get('/',(req,res)=\>{
return res.send();
})

app.get('/data', function (req, res) {
return res.send(obj);
});

app.listen(8080,()=\>{
console.log("Servidor ON");
});
```

Comment: What do you think this does `const writeTofile = ()=\>{`

Comment: `()=\>{` looks like it should be `() = {`, is this some kind of escaping issue or is this the real code?

Comment: That was from a code example I found here. 

https://blog.theashishmaurya.me/how-to-read-and-write-from-csv-file-in-nodejs#heading-1-creating-your-method-to-write-to-file

Comment: You have an escaping issue when you coped the code from there (also typo'd in my comment). It should be `() => {` not `() =\> {`

Comment: I have changed that to your recommendation, it does create and write the headers, but it is not picking up OBJ(s) and writing them from the let data statement. 

I do not know what needs to be done to get it write a new line for all of the OBJ data.

Comment: Try adding the append flag to your file write command. You can look that up in the Node documentation. Otherwise, 1) delete this question 2) use an online tool to get the correct indentation for your code. 3) copy your code and eliminate everything not relevant to the problem 4) open up a new question and explain exactly what you are trying to do and what the problem is